# WPF Datagrid : Column Minimum widths and horizontal scroll bar

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Is this possible to implement (Let's say, I have WPF Datagrid with 4 columns) :

1. I want to set some minimum widths to columns (but only for auto resize)
2. Once window, shrinks below some size (less than sum of minimum widths of all columns)
3. But user shall be able to resize the column to zero size if desired.

Why I am looking for this is, if minimum width is set to zero, on resizing window, columns squeezes into each other and UI looks very bad. And horizontal scroll bar never appears.

In short, I am looking for best strategy to implement for minimum width and horizontal scroll bar for datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example of how to implement responsive design in `WPF` and `xaml` in particular: 
[A XAML implementation of CSS responsive design (WPF, WinRT, WP8)](http://klingdigital.net/2014/03/xaml-responsive-design-media-queries/) .

Another option will be to use `DataTriggers` with `Converters` to *adapt* layout changes depending on parent item `ActualWidth`:

```
<DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=[parentElement], Converter={StaticResource isSizeLessThan}, ConverterParameter=200}">
    <!-- Change layout -->
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: @Anatolli, sorry for coming back very late on this. 
Regarding issue, I am trying to change minimum width using 'DataTrigger' to some other value once Datagrid reaches to certain width; But it is not working (but it works on event handler). Any clue here? Also I am not too sure if this idea is good as suddenly after changing minimum width, all columns will try to adjust to new width and user may have "Columns are jumping" feeling.